# Gridview Pop-Up display for more detail information

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have **one strong entity** table, "General".

There are **two weak entity table** that points to "General"; 
Hardware_Information" and "Software_Information"; each weak entity table contains different columns.

A Gridview is presenting the table "General".

Question: **How do I code, so that when user clicks one row from "General" gridview, it will trace back to the right weak entity table and shows information from the weak entity table?**

I am using ASP.NET C# and SQL Server.

*English is not my native and I am really noob in programming. Apologies if my question is not clear but help is desperately needed.*

Comment: What's the logic to decide `right weak entity table`?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Hi, thank you for your time. "General" table has primary key. Each primary key in "General" uniquely identifies one row of information either from "Hardware_Information" and "Software_Information".

Comment: The weak entity table, "Hardware_Information" and "Software_Information" have different column of data, thus the data is different. Let say the PK in "General" is running number, "1" and "2". "1" will point to a row in "Hardware_Information"; while "2" will point to a row at "Software_Information". I cannot use FK at the weak entity tables, because its one-to-one relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Hope  this can help you in coding for your requirement.

use jQuery to display or show gridview row details in modal popup window on button click in asp.net using c#

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function openPopup(productid, productname, price) {
                    $('#lblId').text(productid);
                    $('#lblName').text(productname);
                    $('#lblPrice').text(price);
                    $("#popupdiv").dialog({
                        title: "jQuery Show Gridview Row Details in Popup",
                        width: 300,
                        height: 250,
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: {
                            Close: function () {
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            </script>
            <style type="text/css">
                .GridviewDiv {
                    font-size: 100%;
                    font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, Arial, Helevetica, sans-serif;
                    color: #303933;
                }

                .headerstyle {
                    color: #FFFFFF;
                    border-right-color: #abb079;
                    border-bottom-color: #abb079;
                    background-color: #df5015;
                    padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
                    text-align: center;
                }
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <form id="form2" runat="server">
                    <div>
                        <div id="popupdiv" title="Basic modal dialog" style="display: none">
                            Product Id:
                            <label id="lblId"></label>
                            <br />
                            Product Name:
                            <label id="lblName"></label>
                            <br />
                            Price:
                            <label id="lblPrice"></label>
                        </div>
                        <table align="center" style="margin-top: 200px">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="GridviewDiv">
                                        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvDetails" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="420px">
                                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerstyle" />
                                            <Columns>
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="productid" HeaderText="Product Id" />
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="productname" HeaderText="Product Name" />
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="price" HeaderText="Price" />
                                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <a href="#" class="gridViewToolTip" onclick='openPopup("<%# Eval("productid")%>","<%# Eval("productname")%>","<%# Eval("price")%>")'>test</a>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                            </Columns>
                                        </asp:GridView>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </body>
</html>

      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindGridview();
            }
        }
        protected void BindGridview()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Suresh;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=MySampleDB"))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from productinfo", con);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(ds);
                con.Close();
                gvDetails.DataSource = ds;
                gvDetails.DataBind();
            }
        }
```